# Google reCAPTCHA V2 JavaScript We detected that your site is not verifying reCAPTCHA solutions

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

Error Message
**We detected that your site is not verifying reCAPTCHA solutions. This is required for the proper use of reCAPTCHA on your site. Please see our developer site for more information.**
I created this reCaptcha code, it works well but I don not know how can I validate it, I thought it was validating with the function
`grecaptcha.getResponse();` but it was not so.
Apparently The recaptcha worked well on the website but I just saw in Google admin the next message:
[image]

**Requirements:**
1.Do not use `action="file.php"` in the form, only a javascript function in the form.

```html
     <!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head >
    <title></title>
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function get_action() {
            var v = grecaptcha.getResponse();
            console.log("Resp" + v );
            if (v == '') {
                document.getElementById('captcha').innerHTML = "You can't leave Captcha Code empty";
                return false;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('captcha').innerHTML = "Captcha completed";
                return true;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" onsubmit="return get_action();">
    <div>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdNIlAUAAAAADS_uVMUayu5Z8C0tw_jspdntbYl"></div>
    </div>
   <input type="submit" value="Button" />
   
    <div id="captcha"></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

May you help me Please. I would appreciate it a lot
How can I validate it since I need to use a javascript function `onsubmit="return get_action();"` instead of `action="file.php"` *when I submit?:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `grecaptcha.getResponse()` function will only provide you with the user response token, which then must be validated with `HTTP POST` call on google reCAPTCHA server.

You could use AJAX request, to validate the token, but these validations **should always be done on server side**, for security reasons - JavaScript could've always been meddled with by user and tricked into believing that reCAPTCHA was successfully verified.

[Google reCAPTCHA docs](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify):

> After you get the response token, you need to verify it with reCAPTCHA using the following API to ensure the token is valid.

So what you need to do is to send your reCAPTCHA secret (second key that was generated for you in reCAPTCHA admin page) and user response token (the one received from `grecaptcha.getResponse()` function) to reCAPTCHA API as described in [reCAPTCHA docs](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify).

**In PHP**, you'd do somethink like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query([
    'secret'   => YOUR_RECAPTCHA_SECRET,
    'response' => USER_RESPONSE_TOKEN,
]));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$response = @json_decode($data);

if ($response && $response->success)
{
    // validation succeeded, user input is correct
}
else
{
    // response is invalid for some reason
    // you can find more in $data->{"error-codes"}
}
```

Comment: I'm doing this on the server side, yet I get the same warning. The warning comes with no information whatsoever about the responses that supposedly were not verified. Not even the number of requests and the date of the last one. For all I know it could be a warning from one non-verified response from 5 years ago. Is there a place in the admin console where  I can get detailed information?? If anybody from Google is listening, your APIs and documentation are a disaster.

Comment: @matteo (sorry, I know this is old), Agree, documentation is useless (and the reports as well). I am running into the same thing, everything is working properly, doing all the appropriate server side work, but getting this message for all sites I am working with.  I am beginning to wonder if it is because I do not send out the challenge to google if the form fails for other reasons (the email is invalid), I only send out the challenge, once the form is filled out properly.

Comment: @Katie So did you have any luck with this?

Comment: @chemark Not really, I just checked and still getting some fails in reports, but have concluded it means nothing :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would suggest...

1.) Append a query string to your reCPATCHA script. Also for better performance, prevents render blocking, you can add `async defer` attributes to your `<script ...>`. And for correctness you should move the script to after the `<form>` in the DOM. `...</form> <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=recaptchaRender' async defer></script>`.

2.) Add a new function called `recaptchaRender()`. To handle your validation to Google and offload the response to you callback `get_action`. Replace `RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY` to with your Google site key.

```
function recaptchaRender{
    grecaptcha.render( 'reCaptchSubmit', {
        'sitekey': 'RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY',
        'callback': get_action
    });
}
```

3.) Add `id="reCaptchSubmit"` to your submit button.

4.) Remove `onsubmit="return get_action();"` from your form element.

Essentially you were missing the authentication between your script and Google.  This doesn't handle your forms validation, but will at least get you to your render callback `get_action()`, where you can handle validation - might want to rename to something more relevant i.e. `validateForm()` etc

Comment: This solution will not validate user's response against reCAPTCHA servers in any way either. This solution is not valid.

Comment: Your right. I was pointing out what was broken with the OPs code. Should have stuck to the point hinting at validation.