# I am getting this error in google captcha console

Tags: php

I am getting this error "We detected that your site is verifying reCAPTCHA passed solutions less than 50% of the time. This could indicate a problem with your integration with reCAPTCHA. Please see our developer site for more information." on my admin console.

I have verified my site according to this link(https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify#api-request). but now I am still facing this above error. I can't able to find the solution of this error.

how can I solve this error?

Comment: Is it working in the UI, or do you find any issues while implementing in the UI? Could you please let us know or provide a screenshot to understand

Comment: I have faced this issue on google captcha admin console. (see screenshot: http://prntscr.com/n68u0k). and also, I get the success response from this "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify" API.

Comment: Check this link, I guess it will be helpful to resolve your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49592772/google-recaptcha-v2-javascript-we-detected-that-your-site-is-not-verifying-recap

Comment: Yes. I have used this code of this link.(See screenshot: http://prntscr.com/n68y52)