# VueRecaptcha - We detected that your site is not verifying reCAPTCHA solutions

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, recaptcha

Implemented as per instructions provided by this link. https://github.com/DanSnow/vue-recaptcha

Using VueJS framework to meet our requirements.

Getting this message on our google recaptcha dashboard screen:

We detected that your site is not verifying reCAPTCHA solutions. This is required for the proper use of reCAPTCHA on your site. Please see our developer site for more information.

But, not sure whether need to send any google recaptcha execute code after success once submit button clicked. Any help to solve this issue soon pls?

Comment: Can you show your implementation? Or a link to it?

Comment: To properly answer this question we need a [mcve] to verify what is going on. I am guessing it is something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49592772/google-recaptcha-v2-javascript-we-detected-that-your-site-is-not-verifying-recap where you do not verify the recaptcha server-side, which means that you get a recaptcha verification token that you do not check against the api to see if it is actually valid.